# Undefined variable: _SESSION php login script

Tags: php, session

I'm new to PHP and am even more of a beginner when it comes to sessions. I have my **index.php** page, which is where users can register and login. The forms are posting to submit.php, respectively for registering and logging in.

This is the **dashboard.php** file where i showed the username of a user and email address from which account he's login.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "includes/config.php";
include "layouts/header.php";
$s_title = "Superior Results";
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
 $sql = "SELECT email, username FROM members";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
```

And this is how i call these session variables in dashboard.php file

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>   
<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>
```

Username works but email didn't work it shows Notice: **Undefined index: email**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDat4.png)

Comment: Yes, and where do you *set* those `$_SESSION` variables? I'm missing something like `$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email']`.

Comment: Where did you set the value of $_SESSION['email']? Are you sure you did it?

Comment: i didn't set those variables anywhere... it should fetch from sessions of the user account. sorry im little confused with this

Comment: @VictorArcas In the Netherlands we call this `spuit elf`. No worries, a translation will not help you.

Comment: @VictorArcas no i didn't set any value... it should fetch according to which account the user has logged in.

Comment: this isn't a live site, is it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i asked this question! can you please take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056352/how-this-form-is-working-php-mysql-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the user logs in you need to set the session variables

```
 $sql = "SELECT email, username FROM members WHERE id = '".$confirmed login id from the login process."' ";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
$SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

Once those session variables are set after they log in, you can use them on any other page that is part of that session (has session_start() on the first line)

Comment: When i did login from another account which includes different email it still showed me my first account email address.. http://i.imgur.com/jZgtBih.png .... http://i.imgur.com/lBomGSQ.png .... http://i.imgur.com/dkBpxfx.png

Comment: @NoorQureshi If you would delete your `PHPSESSID` cookie in your browser, that issue will likely be resolved as this code would work if you set the `id` in this query correctly.

Comment: @Xorifelse yes i did it didn't worked.. I'm doing something wrong here: http://i.imgur.com/xZvzhzk.png ..... the username output seems to be working correctly and 'email' causing issue...

Comment: @guesterator_php If you'd update the code with error correction and properly `fetch()` for `1` expected result (as I didn't in my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42590690/revisions)), I'll upvote. Also, you're selecting `email` and `username` and **not** `$row['id']` which shouldn't happen in the first place because that is already known.

Comment: @NoorQureshi Because I'm not seeing a `WHERE` clause in that picture. that means it selects every row from your table. Since you should only expect 1 result from 1 user `id`, that should not happen.

Comment: The issue is resolved! Thanks @guesterator_php   --->   $sql = "SELECT email, username FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";

Comment: @NoorQureshi Uuhm, no problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that you're trying to read an array key that doesn't exist. The `isset()` function is there so you can test for this. There's no need for null checks as you never assign null to an element:

```
// check that the 'email' key exists
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  // it does; output the message
  echo $_SESSION['email'];

  // remove the key so we don't keep outputting the message
  unset($_SESSION['email']);
}
```

Well, just for your comments below, I´m not sure if I understand your needs, but you want to do something like this:?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
if(($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) != false){
  if(($row = $result->fetch_assoc() !== null)){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row;
  } else {
    echo 'no rows in database';
  }
} else {
  echo 'You have an error in you mysql syntax';
}
//.. work with concrete user
```

Comment: Please explain how to set it perhaps?

Comment: session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = "qureshi@gmail.com";
echo $_SESSION['email'];

Comment: it redirected me to my index.php page and didn't let me login with my username/password http://i.imgur.com/CgOepR0.png when i isset email..

Comment: @MarekBernád it will have multi users signup to my script and it should echo email according to there profile!

Comment: @NoorQureshi Great, keep in mind a `$_SESSION` is client specific **!**

Comment: @Xorifelse what will be the best way to display user profile information from mysql according to his account information?

Comment: Because you responded and resolved the issue with it, +1